# Export data from a datablock to an Excel form in Oracle

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-xp, database

I want to export a data block data (a table of data included header and column data) into an Excel form. I use Oracle 6. Would you please help me to solve my problem?

Would you please provide a complete example for me?

My OS is Windows XP with Oracle Form v6

Comment: Why don't you use Oracle SQL Developer to import Excel file Many Oracle IDEs offer this feature, would be much easier ! **In Oracle sql developer go to Tables, then select import data, select your excel file, it will display the column, import the data into a table**. ☺

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your issue totally but if you have Oracle form v6 on your client then i guess that you are talking to a database RDBMS version x SID x therefore you can use sqlplus (you find that in your V6 installation) and spool your table query to a csv file which you can open with excel.

You can explicitly format the query to produce a delimited string with something along the lines of:

```
start sqlplus

connect user/password@some database SID

---

set echo off

set feedback off

set linesize 1000

set pagesize 0

set sqlprompt ''

set trimspool on

set headsep off

spool output.csv

select '"'||column1||'","'||column2||'"' from table_name;

results...
results...

spool off
```

---

Open the csv file in Excel.

Comment: cool idea, but we already moved to oracle 12c and the solution which I used was write a package to create excel, the way you suggested has less security and end user might not be able to do it as easy as possible.